# rails & rspec; how to test smtpapi batch substitutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, smtp

My app uses smtpapi substitution to send a single email that contains the smtpapi headers containing the names and email addresses of N people. Sendgrid then does that 'mail merge' and sends N emails.

My Rspec specs are able to test that an outgoing email contains the right smtpapi headers for N people, which in theory means there will be N emails sent.

Is there any way in Rspec to take the testing to the next step: actually perform a simulated send WITH smtpapi substitution so my specs can verify N emails are 'sent', and each email contains the right info. As a trivial example, check the N 'sent' emails and make sure that the username and email were correctly mail-merged in each of N emails?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an RSpec question, in my opinion, since you're not really talking about testing Ruby. As you point out, the mail merge and actual mailing is occurring within sendgrid and there are no sendgrid hooks for those processes, let alone a Ruby interface to them. The only thing I can think of to do would be to test the actual *receipt* of the mail by the recipients

Comment: What you say also applies when testing SMS messaging, yet there is a invaluable gem called sms-spec that permits Rspec testing of SMS messages. Perhaps someone has cleverly done the same for email.

Comment: If the OP were just talking about testing the interaction with Ruby/Rails mailing interfaces, then I would agree with you.  There is https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec in particular. However, in this case the OP is explicitly the capabilities of sendgrid. They can test their interface *to* sendgrid, but to test that sendgrid is interpreting the instructions correctly and attempting to deliver the mail to all the right recipients, you have to get help from sendgrid.

Comment: Sendgrid is incidental. I'm hoping to test what outbound emails looks like after undergoing smtpapi substitution. I'm not trying to test Sendgrid per se (who happens to be one such vendor who provides that capability). It's not hard to imagine a testing gem (or an smtpapi substitution gem) MIGHT exist that, given an ActionMailer email object, might then create some array of N emails that reflect the original email with the smtpapi substitution applied.

Comment: Unless I'm really missing something, SMTPAPI is sendgrid's unique API and the substitution that takes place is sendgrid-unique and taking place within sendgrid itself in the cloud. If you're just talking about using ActionMailer, then you've got the gem I referenced in my earlier message, but that doesn't do any fancy mail-merge that I know of. If you're open to a client-based mail merge capability, then you could just stub the mail-merge's SMTP calls.